# How to remove or include errorbar plot from matplotlib axes?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

This code shows an Attribute error:

I am plotting errorbar plot for let's say 10 different datasets (huge datasets) from a file containing multiple datasets (let's say for different days), and I am showing the user an option (Checkbox) to remove or include a plot of the particular dataset (through GUI).

So for this, I just want to erase the current axes and at a later time want to redraw it again.

How can I do this?

Below is a simplified example to show what I need.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
x, y, yerr = np.random.rand(3,10)
l  = ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr, marker='s', mfc='red', mec='green', ms=20, mew=4)

canvas = fig.canvas
canvas.draw()
bkg = canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)

plt.show()
plt.pause(1)


ax.clear()
canvas.restore_region(bkg)
ax.draw_artist(l) 

# here it throws an AttributeError: 'ErrorbarContainer' 
#object has no attribute 'draw'
```

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to use set_alpha(0) for every child of the container?

Comment: @SamProell I don't want it to go invisible, I wanted to have it removed from the plot and redraw at a later time if I wanted to see it again.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really see the point in going the complicated way.. After ax.clear, you could also always call ax.errorbar again. But anyways, one problem here is, that errorbar returns an ErrorbarContainer, which is not an Artist itself and therefore has no draw method. You would have to work with the children of the container (`for child in l.get_chilren(): ...`). In addition, ax.clear() removes the artists from the plot so I think you would have to do `ax.add_artist` instead of `draw_artist`

Comment: @SamProell The point is, I am plotting errorbar plot for let's say 10 different datasets (huge datasets) from a file containing multiple datasets (let's say for different days), and I am showing the user an option (Checkbox) to remove or include a plot of the particular dataset (through GUI).

Comment: i see. have you tried using `add_artist` for every child of `l`?

Comment: @SamProell the error bar plot seems to have two artist, one is line and other is rectangle. So ```l``` is a list of two elements. I could ```add_artist``` for the line using ```l[0]``` but could not ```add_artist``` the yerr bar from the ```l[1]```.

Comment: that's weird, this gist works for me: https://gist.github.com/SamProell/7f44f739895bd717ad3c6ea53fc52d44

Comment: @SamProell I will try it. Thanks